# Boto3 ec2 describe_instances always returns empty

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a very simple sandbox I'm trying to get to work so I can use it in a bigger application:

```
ec2_client = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

response = ec2_client.describe_instances()
print(response)
```

and it results in...

```
{
  'Reservations': [], 
  'ResponseMetadata': {
    'RequestId': '2c28e8aa-da6d-4ca4-8ea7-f672518cac9f',
    'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
    'HTTPHeaders': {
      'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 
      'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 
      'date': 'Thu, 07 Dec 2017 16:44:30 GMT', 
      'server': 'AmazonEC2'
  }, 
  'RetryAttempts': 0}
}
```

But **the problem** is no matter how many times I run this `Reservations` is ALWAYS empty :(.

In AWS consonle I can CLEARLLY see an instance is running...

[image: running ec2 instance]

I tried starting more instances, restarting the instances I had running. I put my initial script in a loop and ran it on repeat while I did this looking for any sign of the Reservations array actually having data.

I double checked that my aws ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY are both correct and pointing to the correct account. They are.

I have no clue why this is. Its so simple and should be working. I'm new to AWS so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're querying the right region?

Comment: I didn't know I was querying a _specific_ region. Do you know how to specify a specific region?

Comment: Double checked the docs https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances and they don't say anything about querying a specific region. You think maybe its using my location??

Comment: Try `boto3.client(..., region_name='us-xxx-x')`

Comment: ya just got that myself. Make an answer and I'll except it. Thanks @kichik!

Answer (score 5):

Seems that you forgot to add the region.

Set the region when creating your client

```
ec2_client = boto3.client(
  'ec2',
  aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
  region_name=REGION_NAME
)

response = ec2_client.describe_instances()
print(response)
```

If your EC2 instances are in Oregon, you can do `region_name='us-west-2'`

Hard coding credentials is not recommended. You can configure your profiles using the `awscli` and then reference it in your code.

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
# Any clients created from this session will use credentials
# from the [dev] section of ~/.aws/credentials.
ec2_client = session.client('ec2')
```

You can read more about Boto3 credentials [Boto3 Credentials](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that somehow boto3 was using a region that my instance was not running in. The solution was to specify the region when initializing the client:

```
ec2_client = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    region_name='us-east-2',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
```

All credit to @kichik for telling me where to look!