# Describe_instances in boto3 with filters is not working

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, filter

I am developing a script in Python for deleting old AMIs and its snapshots. For testing purposes, I have been trying to create and right after deleting an AMI. My code for creating the instance is the following (including the addition of tags at the end):

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

today = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d')

remove_on = (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y%m%d')

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='eu-west-1')
client = session.client('ec2')
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')

instance_info = client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Name', 
'Values': ['Airflow']}]) #This filter DOES work
instance_id = instance_info['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)

image = instance.create_image(InstanceId=instance_id, Name=f"Airflow_{today}")
time.sleep(2)
image.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'RemoveOn', 'Value': remove_on},
                        {'Key': 'BackupOf', 'Value': 'Airflow'}])
```

However, when I try to get the info of the recent created AMI, I get no data:

```
instances_to_delete = client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:RemoveOn', 
                                                      'Values':[remove_on]}])
```

I have tried to explicitly put a string in Values but it does not work either. Also, even though it didn't make much sense (since I already had one filter working previously), I specified the region in client also (because of these answers [Boto3 ec2 describe_instances always returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700089/boto3-ec2-describe-instances-always-returns-empty)) and it doesn't work.
[image]
The tag is there as we can see in the following screenshot

Comment: You say that you are trying to "get the info of the recent created AMI", then the code then shows `describe_instances`. Which one are you actually wanting to do? Did you intend to put the tag on the instance, or the image?

Comment: Well, that was the whole mistake. I was looking for instances to delete but I should have looked for images to delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be creating an image (AMI) and then putting a tag on the AMI.

Then, you are saying that it is unable to find the **instance** with that tag. That makes sense, because only the **image** was tagged, not the instance.